# ADC using S7 1200

Tags: plc

I have a project on temperature control system using s7 1200,my analogue input temperature range is 0 to 100 degree centigrade and thermocouple sensor gives 10mV per degree centigrade,do i need to connect an op-amp to amplify the output of the sensor for the adc conversion in plc?

Comment: What accuracy do you want?

Comment: What input module are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of accuracy you need for your data. If the analog input module has 12-bit ADC with -10..10V range, then it has 11 bits (values 0 to 2047) from 0 to 10 volts. Your signal value is 0 to 1 volts, so you'll get the range of values from 0 to 204 for a voltage range from 0 to 1 volts. (204 = 2048/10). (Or you might get values from 1024 to 1228 if the value is unsigned - you'll need to test this). So if the numeric precision of 0.5 degrees is enough for you, then you don't need the amplifier.

Note that the 0.5 degrees is the *precision* of the value, not the *accuracy* of the value. Accuracy may be less, depending on the sensor and the connection.

Edit: recognized the fact that there are several analog signal modules to choose from and others might have a different accuracy than 12 bits.

Comment: If I am using a 12 bit input module then is it possible to use only 8 bits?and can you plz suggest that i should use 12 bits or 8 bits?

Comment: More bits gives you more precision. I think you should not concentrate on the number of bits, rather think about the range of numbers that you will get from the sensor and whether a step from one number to the next would be accurate enough for you. I don't know the precision requirement for your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using S71200 PLC the input range might be of 0-10Vdc type and your thermocouple sensor gives you 10mV output. Generally PLC can accept the standard 0-10Vdc or 4-20mA current 
you can put temperature controller in between which are of output 0-10Vdc in case of using on board I/O of S71200.